# Mocking a method that returns a method call to another object

Tags: c#, unit-testing, mocking, moq

I'm currently unit testing my code and I have problem with creating a mock using Moq. I'm unit testing Foo, and I wish to mock User.GetSomething() to isolate the test. I have created a qick sample of the code that I wish to test:

```
public class User(){
    public List<int> GetSomething(){
         return bar.CreateList();
     }
}


public class Foo(User user){
   public int SomeMethod() {
      var x = User.GetSomething()
      Do something with x
      ...
    }
}
```

I have tried creating a mock by doing the following. I have excluded the assert and unnecessary arrange for this question:

```
var mock = new Mock<User>();
List<int> someList = new List<int>(){1, 2, 3};
mock.Setup(u => u.CreateList()).Returns(SomeList);

Foo(mock.object)
var res = Foo.SomeMethod();
etc.
```

But I get the exception: `System.NotSupportedException : Unsupported expression: u => u.CreateList()`

`Non-overridable members (here: User.CreateList) may not be used in setup / verification expressions.`

Comment: You cannot mock not an overridable methods. In your case, you can change GetSomething() to following  `public virtual List<int> GetSomething()`

Comment: @SergeyAnisimov that should be an answer

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The issue is that, as it says; `CreateList` is not overrideable, it's not marked `virtual` and, the input is a concrete (`User`), and not an interface (`IUser`).

So to fix this you have 2 options:

1. Create an `IUser` interface and use this in your code.
2. Mark the targeted User methods as `virtual`

Answer (score 2):

You cannot mock not an overridable methods. In your case, you can change GetSomething() to following: `public virtual List<int> GetSomething()`